# Model includes list of objects

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, model

I try to build a model including several properties and a List of objects like this:

```
public class A
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string AnyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<A> AList {get; set;}
}
```

The problem is, in the controller for creating an object of Type A I want to create a new List "As" and add it to an (existing or new) object of Type B.
Therefore I write:

```
db.Bs.Find(id).AList = new List<A> {a};
```

But after calling this List in the details view of B it always says NullReferenceException because AList is still null.
It seems that the database doesn't safe AList, what can I do to safe the list?

Comment: what is db? do you use entity framework ?

Comment: db is the databaseContext for A and B.
Do I have to use public virtual A {get; set;} or can I do this with Lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one-to-many relationship must be declared as a `virtual ICollection<>`.

```
public class B
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<A> AList {get; set;}
}
```

And you not have to instanciate the member `AList`. Just add it your `A` object.

```
db.Bs.Find(id).AList.Add(a);
```